# Associating an Elastic IP Address with the Secondary Private IPv4 Address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, boto

I need to associate an Elastic IP Address with the Secondary Private IPV4 address by using boto3.

I have studied the AWS documentation to do it from a console or CLI method.

But, I need to do with python boto3.

Reference Documents: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html#StepThreeEIP
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/associate-address.html

Answer (score 0):

You would call the EC2 Client `associate_address` method, documented [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.associate_address).